# How do I keep session for a very long time alive?

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

I've used this:

```
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","360000");
session_start();
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $row['id'];
```

I don't have acces to the server settings. I want to keep sessions for a very long time alive, like until 2012.

Comment: Don't do that. Sessions aren't intended for this. Use cookies.

Comment: lololol. making a "will you be alive after dec. 2012" app or something? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to keep up sessions until 2012 anyway. If you want something for a long time, that is where cookies can be put to use. You can take a look at [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function of php for more information.